# RestSharp.Portable - IgnoreResponseStatusCode property does not work on UWP apps?

Tags: c#, .net, win-universal-app, uwp, restsharp

I am currently using `RestSharp.Portable` for a while now and I used to set the `IgnoreResponseStatusCode` of the `RestClient` class to `true` in order to manage errors (especially connectivity errors) by myself.

Here a very simple example in a Windows Phone 8.1 app using the universal project and the `RestSharp.Portable.HttpClient` in version 3.1.0 :

```
try
{
    var client = new RestClient("http://www.google.fr") { IgnoreResponseStatusCode = false };
    var request = new RestRequest() {Method = Method.GET };
    var data = await client.Execute(request);

    Debug.WriteLine(data.IsSuccess == true ? "success" : "failed");
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(exception.Message);
}
```

If I do not have an internet connection, the code throws  a `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException` exception with the message `Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).`.

And now, if I set the `IgnoreResponseStatusCode` property to `true`, the code does not throw any exception. This is the behavior expected, I mean the behavior I have since I use this library.

The issue appears when I am trying to execute the same code on a UWP app with the same version of the `RestSharp.Portable.HttpClient` library.

It seems that the `IgnoreResponseStatusCode` does not work and, if I do not have an internet connection, the code throws the following exception (no matter the value is set to `true` or `false`) : `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException` with the message `An error occurred while sending the request.`

Is there a way to do not throw an exception in this case ? Is this an issue into the `RestSharp.Portable.HttpClient` library or is this a normal behavior of the UWP ?

Thx for your help.

Edit : If I use `RestSharp.Portable.WebRequest` instead of `RestSharp.Portable.HttpClient` it seems to work correctly

Comment: Hello. How about checking internet connection before calling the request? instead of manipulating library properties? Do you need this exact way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that my question is old and the library is not maintain anymore, but the author of the library answered the question on [github](https://github.com/FubarDevelopment/restsharp.portable/issues/54) directly:

> The behavior is - sadly - inconsistent across all platforms, because all implementations of HttpClient (not RestSharp.Portable) have subtle differences. I'll try to iron out all those differences, but it can take some time. I'll leave this ticket open for now.